# Exclude role from product fees Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, roles

i have a plugin that add fees to the products that i want, this is applied for every role of the website, i need to exclude some roles from that fees, before it worked with this code:

```
    public function add_fees( $cart ) {
    $fees = $this->get_fees( $cart );
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $allowed_roles = array('b2b_silver_dp','distributore_dp','b2b_gold_dp','b2b_platinum_dp');
    if ( array_intersect( $allowed_roles, $user->role ) ) {
        return $fee;
    }

    foreach ( $fees as $fee ) {
        $cart->add_fee( $fee['name'], $fee['amount'], $fee['taxable'], $fee['tax_class'] );
    }
}
```

This code is inside the plugin that can't be upgraded, I don't know why now after some update of Woocommerce it don't work anymore. Can someone help me?

Comment: Maybe you should contact the plugin author about this first of all.

Comment: the plugin author do not answer from 2 years, i just did it, that because i'm asking here.